# Warnings when using babel with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, babel, unicode, warnings

Recently I have started using LuaLaTeX over pdfLaTeX, without any real issue so far.

When working on a project I have noticed some warning messages I have failed to decpiher after consulting Google and TeXExchange:

```
LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage{t1enc} with
           \usepackage[magyar]{babel}, to get accented chars hyphenated.


LaTeX Warning: Please use \usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
           or \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
           with \usepackage[magyar]{babel}.
```

Currently I am writing my document in english with some hungarian mixed in (my university requires hungarian declarations in a thesis). I use `\usepackage[magyar,english]{babel}` so that both hungarian and english are loaded but english is used by default, then I switch over to hungarian using an `otherlanguage` environment when I need to, like so:

```
... english text ...
\begin{otherlanguage}{magyar}
    ... hungarian text ...
\end{otherlanguage}
... english text ...
```

The warning really is a warning in the sense that hyphenation seems to work just fine.
**Any ideas what produces this warning?** I have been thinking about weird package loading order problems, but trying different permutations didn't get rid of this warning.

Example document producing this error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[magyar,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
This is such a nice document.
\end{document}
```

I compile it using `latexmk -lualatex <file.tex>`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: Very likely nothing wrong, just a language style which has not been updated (`t1enc` is very very old and obsolete). If everything is ok, just ignore the warnings.

Comment: It very much sounds like the warning messages are meant to be issued only under pdfLaTeX -- in case the `inputenc` and/or `fontenc` packages did not get loaded. Under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, these packages shouldn't be loaded anyway as long as `fontspec` is loaded. You may ignore the warning messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this to suppress the warnings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\magyarOptions{suggestions=no}
\usepackage[magyar,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
This is such a nice document.
\end{document}
```

magyar.ldf is quite long and contains lots of adaptions and patches (often optional). It obviously hasn't been adapted to lualatex/xelatex yet. The fontencoding seems to be ok with this engines but there is no garanty that there isn't somewhere code which implicitly assumes an 8-bit engine. So check the output.

Comment: Would you actually suggest doing this? I mean couldn't this potentially suppress actually useful warnings later on?
I am quite suprised to learn that things like this weren't adopted yet, as LuaLaTeX is like 8 years old now and is the offical successor to pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to analyze the code. The option suppresses around 6 "suggestions", you can find them in line 2550-2650. lualatex is not the "official" successor of pdflatex, and things get adapted when someone does it. Ask the maintainer or find someelse with the needed knowledges about tex, luatex and hungarian to do it.

Comment: An upload of the newest magyar.ldf to CTAN is in progress. It should be available soon. It's already available from http://www.math.bme.hu/latex/lakk/texmf/tex/generic/magyar/magyar.ldf (as usual). The newest magyar.ldf doesn't display these warnings when run with lualatex.

Answer (score 4):

These warnings emitted by *magyar.ldf* are harmless if *lualatex* and *fontspec.sty* are used. Until *magyar.ldf* becomes smarter about omitting these warnings, you can use [uni8.sty](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pts/pts-latex-uni8/master/uni8.sty), which loads *t1enc.sty*, *fontenc.sty*, *inputenc.sty*, *luainputenc.sty*, *fontspec.sty*, *babel.sty* and hyphenation patterns correctly (and suppresses useless warnings emitted by *magyar.ldf*). Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\PassOptionsToPackage{english,magyar}{babel}
\usepackage[fontspec]{uni8}
\begin{document}
This is such a nice document.
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, loading the packages above correctly (so that characters and hyphenation are both correct) with *lualatex* is quite tricky if *fontspec.sty* is not used. *uni8.sty* does that correctly as well.